# remove attribute from all tags by class name

Tags: jquery

I have a form with labels styled as class="input"

The labels are positioned inside the form fields, and they are designed to disappear when you type in the field. That is working fine. The problem is when I reset the form after it is submitted.

```
jQuery("#requestform").get(0).reset();
```

This statement will clear the fields, but I also need to remove the "visibility: hidden" attribute from the labels so the labels will reappear.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
jQuery('.formlabel').removeAttr("visibility");
```

here's some sample html from my page:

```
<label class="input">
    <span class="formlabel" style="color: rgb(153, 153, 153); visibility: hidden;">Email</span>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" title="email">
</label>
```

what's wrong with my jQuery? what's the correct way to remove all 'visiblity' attributes from all my class="formlabel" tags?

Cheers!

Comment: Did you know that you only have to write `jQuery` in its long form once? By wrapping your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);`, you can use `$` no matter if `noConflict` has been used or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`visibility` is not an attribute but a CSS property. You need to use `.css('visibility', 'visible')`:

```
$('.formlabel').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

In case you do not need the layout-preserving behaviour of `visibility: hidden` consider using `display: none` - then you can simply use `.show()` to make the element visible.

Comment: works perfect. how do you learn all the ins-and-outs of this stuff! I'm a bit new to jQuery...

Comment: That's kind of obvious. See how it's not `<span visibility="hidden">` but `<span style="visibility:hidden;">` which means it's CSS and not an attribute (`style` is one)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.formlabel').css('visibility', '');
```